# Photoshop only prints in B&W on Pixma Pro 9000, MK2

Tags: canon, photoshop, troubleshooting, printing

One week ago I purchased the Canon Pixma Pro 9000, mk2.  Using photoshop, every print I printed, up to today, was breathtakingly beautiful in all sizes.  8x10,11x14,13x19's looked like you could literally reach into the photo & grab an object. I could not have been happier (unless I won the lottery), with what appeared to be an incredible color printer.

However, (here comes the bad news), today, after spending a few hours on a composition & finally getting it perfect, I thought I would print a 13 x 19.  Using photoshop on my Mac, I selected print.  After listening to the printhead make passes on the Ilford 13x19 blank sheet, I was astounded that the hours of hard composition work, came out in Black & White - no color. After examining all the selectable features on the photoshop print menu - everything appeared to be in order.  I had convinced myself that a "fluke" had happened & the next time, the photo would come out fine. Well, nothing I printed again came out in color - everything is  B & W.

I was totally baffled, so I called Canon technical support.  After answering all their questions, it was suggested to print a "test page" - which came out perfectly in color. Support had "no viable" answer as to what was happening to the printer & why it was printing in B & W. Together, support & I tried multiple times to print anything in color - to no avail. The technician asked to to hold on, while he checked the customer database. After 10 minutes, he returned with no sufficient answer to the problem. He suggested my "permissions" on my Mac were not up to date.

Frustrated from not getting a helpful solution to the ongoing problems I was experiencing, I decided to try printing a color print from Apple's Aperture photo software ("a photoshop type of compositing & editing package").  Expecting another B&W print, I was totally "shocked" to see a spectacularly beautiful print.  So, the problem is:  My beloved Photoshop (two versions) will NOT print in color - suddenly. However, Apple's Aperture will print ( all sizes) to the Pixma.  Does anyone have a clue about what is happening?

Comment: A Photoshop preferences reset seems to have fixed the issue in one case - http://hintsforums.macworld.com/archive/index.php/t-93113.html

Comment: Printer MAY have a monochrome flag in setup options when you print. Different apps MAY treat this differently. What happens if you print an image from Photoshop that previously worked OK in colour?

Comment: try calling adobe tech support, also, reset your settings

Comment: what's your color scheme in the print dialog?

Comment: have you fixed the problem? the same issue (

Comment: are you saving the photoshop files into to .jpeg format. I couldn't find an article on it but it's possible the printer doesn't support the .psd file type.

Comment: Check to see if you have "printer manages color" or "photoshop manages color" set in photoshop.

Comment: maybe you could take a look here : [Photoshop or printer issue: why are colored JPGs printing in B&W?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/66076/photoshop-or-printer-issue-why-are-colored-jpgs-printing-in-bw?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

When Using the Canon Pro 10 printer, I was having issues where my prints where coming out slightly red on the photos and I was able to determine that the driver had a color matching set to Driver Matching and when I changed it to none, and set Lightroom to load the correct color settings for the paper type and quality, everything came out correct again.

I learned this from the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1svDvqBwpPI) posted by Adobe for controlling your printer and it's settings from Lightroom. The tutorial is on YouTube.

I am running Windows 10 with Lightroom but I suspect from the tutorial that Mac and Windows isn't all that much different in controlling the printer driver and setting up Lightroom.

[image: Setting color matching to none]

[image: Have Lightroom control color settings]