# Photoshop or printer issue: why are colored JPGs printing in B&W?

Tags: photoshop, printing

I have an issue in Photoshop. A printer prints my colored images (jpg) in black and white. Other colored images (were not created by me, in me photoshop) print as is in color.

The [same problem](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/24817/photoshop-only-prints-in-bw-on-pixma-pro-9000-mk2) was not answered.

**Printer**: Epson (don't known) I have printed it in the printing service.

**Image format**: jpg.

I think, this is the wrong photoshop settings. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Please add more details. What file formats? What printer?

Comment: In general, it's better to refresh old, unanswered questions rather than re-asking them.

Comment: @mattdm it was not mine question (

Comment: But it's still the _same_ question, right? See http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1712/how-do-i-refresh-a-question

Comment: @mattdm have you seen a link to that question?

Comment: I do see the link. But it seems to be exactly the same problem, not a twist on it, at least assuming that it's a photoshop issue and not specific to the printer model.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have resolved this issue. It's Photoshop problem. My and printing service's photoshops have different color profiles. In printing dialog the option "Allow using printer colors" (or something like this) should be selected. In this case printer will control color profile - will use printer colors. So it's a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I needed to install the correct printer application then in the print dialogue box drop down menu, Select Printer Features. Change colour mode settings, from black & white to Colour.

[image]