# Canon Pixma Pro9000 Mark II Printed Images Too Warm

Tags: canon, printing, color-management

I have a Canon Pixma Pro9000 Mark II photo printer which I use to print photos on Canon Photo Paper Plus Glossy II. I am having some trouble getting printed photos to match the previews I am seeing on my screen. Specifically, the printed pictures appear too warm. I was printing from Preview on my Mac. My settings are:

- Size: 4x6 Borderless
- Color Matching: Canon Color Matching
- Media Type: Photo Paper Plus Glossy II N (although I am printing on Photo Paper Plus Glossy II, according to a site I found a while ago, I should use the media type Plus Glossy II N - Is this incorrect?)
- Print Quality: High
- Color Options:

[image: Color Options]

So my questions are:

1. Why would my pictures appear so warm?
2. How can I fix this problem, either temporarily or permanently?

Comment: Are you printing from lightroom or photoshop directly? or via another method?

Comment: I'm using the MacOS app "Preview"

Comment: Try this - http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/88148/6327 - it's focused on lightroom but it might work with preview as well for setting color matching to none. I had the same issue with the Canon Pro 10 until i just defaulted the color matching.

Comment: Have you verified that your monitor is properly displaying the images? Uncalibrated monitors are often too bright and too cool.

Comment: @MichaelClark I have tested on two different Apple computers and a Dell monitor. All of them look cooler than the print

Comment: You should calibrate your monitor, and you should also "calibrate" your print settings & paper selection until you're happy with the results.  There's no magic fix here.

Comment: @NoahL Almost all monitors come from the factory adjusted to 6500K and brightness set to well above 120cd/mm². If none of the monitors in question have been measured with a colorimeter then you're just chasing the wind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix, Option 1 (temporary, easiest and maybe quickest) : In the 'Color Options' screen of the **Print** panel, you could try sliding the Cyan colour slider towards the right ('High'), experiment with amount setting, and **maybe** a bit of the yellow (again, experiment with amount setting, in either direction), to get the colour closest to your satisfaction .

As to *Why*, possibly your monitor screen isn't properly calibrated, so, to fix, Option 2 (for more long term results) : On your Mac, there is a means of **Calibrating** your monitor screen, to show colour more in agreement with printer over a period of time.

In **System Preferences** app > **Displays** button > **Color** button > **Calibrate** button, and follow on-screen instructions from there.
It's not a bad idea to do this process periodically, because over time, the accuracy of your monitor colours change very gradually.

A 3rd option I just discovered (because I don't use **Preview** app often). In **Preview**, under **Tools** menu, there is **Adjust Color option** (option+command+C  key combo). Click that and you get a little panel with options of **Temperature**   and  **Tint**  . Try playing around with those, before you do the printing in  Preview.  In the case of a "warm" print, slide either of them to the left.

Comment: Thanks! I used the first temporary fix to get it. For the three color sliders (Cyan, Magenta, Yellow), +10, +3, +3 (respectively) did the trick

Answer (score 0):

In the print options, Photoshop specifically, set the **Printer to manage the color**.  That changed everything for me.  Why, because **my printer will not change**.  My laptop will, my display will, my printer will not.  You need to learn what the printer does well and what it doesn't and compensate in Photoshop accordingly.  For this reason, I only print from Adobe Photoshop or Lightroom.  **The client is not basing their love of prints off your computer, only the paper they are printed on.**

I only use Semi-gloss.  That is my personal preference.